# sql1205n when starting db2sampl in windows 7

Tags: sql, db2

My `error` looks like this:

```
SQL1205N  The code page "1208" and/or territory code "0" that has been 
specified is not valid.
```

I've install `db2 express c 10.1v`  on `windows 7 32bit` and I'm trying to start `db2sampl` because I want to start working SAMPLE database that comes with `db2`. How to resolve this error? Any similar experience? 
Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your Locale Settings if they are correct, else you can run these commands in the `db2cmd`

```
db2set DB2CODEPAGE=1208   
db2set DB2TERRITORY=1  
db2set DB2COUNTRY=1  
db2 terminate
```

These should solve your problem according to this [SQL1205N code page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21508099)